# To set special permission for registry key of HKCU for SID user in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to set special permissions for all logged in users using `SID.user` of

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\ .png\Userchoice.
```

I tried the below code snippet but it doesnt seem to work

```bsh
$path = "HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.png\UserChoice"

$Acl = Get-ACL $path

$AccessRule= New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule("user","SpecialPermissions","Allow") -SID $UserProfile.SID

$Acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)

Set-Acl $path $Acl
```

How can we achieve the permission issue to all users ?

Comment: Special Permissions is a custom permission set, not a setting as such? If you want "Special Permissions" you need to specify which exact rights are required

Comment: @Scepticalist, I want to overwrite the key values

Comment: Yes, that's fine, but "SpecialPermissions" is not a a valid value, it;s simply windows-speak for "not a standard set of permissions". Your $AccessRule needs to contain specific permissions. Try changing "SpecialPermissions" to "FullControl" on a test key to see what I mean.

Comment: @Scepticalist, even after providing "Full Control" the permission is not changed for all users

Comment: What do you mean "for all users"? HKCU is the registry part for the currently logged in user. If you want permissions on a user registry key changed for all users you need to load their respective `ntuser.dat` (the file that stores the user registry settings) into the registry and change the permissions there. Do that for all users including "default" (which is the template for new user profiles).

Comment: That setting is a per-user setting. (HKCU means the _Current User_ only) If you want to change the permissions on that registry key for all users, you need to either do it with a logon script or (better) use Group Policy to do that.